# ProgressDialog appears only AFTER the background work (Using AsyncTask). Need it

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I'm using AsyncTask to update a horizontal Progress Dialog. There are no errors. The only thing I can't figure out is that the ProgressDialog appears only after the background work.

**That is, On clicking the button (which in turn does the following:)**

```
    //within concerned OnClick Function of my main class:
    ASYNC_TEST GH=new ASYNC_TEST(this,"something","something","url", "booga");
    String response=GH.execute().get();
```

**the button key remains pressed for a long time (HTTP POSTs are slow), and then suddenly the Progress Dialog appears for no more than a second, completing 100% in one swift go and disappears.**

I'm pasting my code:

Below is the class extending AsyncTask which handles a HTTP Post operation and should be updating the progress bar.

```
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class ASYNC_TEST extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    private String result = "";
    private int ProgressStatus;
    String username, password, THE_URL, YouSure;

    private ProgressDialog pdb;

    public ASYNC_TEST(Context ConT, String username, String password,String THE_URL, String YouSure) 
    {
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Constructor");

        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.THE_URL = THE_URL;
        this.YouSure = YouSure;

        pdb = new ProgressDialog(ConT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {

        pdb.setCancelable(true);
        pdb.setMessage("Logging In. Hold On a Sec...");
        pdb.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pdb.setProgress(0);
        pdb.setMax(100);
        pdb.show();

        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Pre-Execute");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String res) 
    {

        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Post-Execute");
        pdb.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(res);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) 
    {

        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "Progress Update: " + progress[0]);
        pdb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... smt) 
    {
        Log.d("LOG_TAG", "doInBackground: ");

        try {

            ProgressStatus = 0;
            publishProgress(0);

            //Stuff

            ProgressStatus = 10;
            publishProgress(10);

            // More Stuff (HTTP POST)

            ProgressStatus = 20;
            publishProgress(10);

            //....Finally...

            ProgressStatus = 100;
            publishProgress(100);


        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "";

    }
    }
```

Log DATA:

```
    05-18 15:19:52.773: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Constructor
    05-18 15:19:52.822: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Pre-Execute
    05-18 15:19:52.832: D/LOG_TAG(1596): doInBackground: 
    05-18 15:19:53.482: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 13648 objects / 583400 bytes in 77ms
    05-18 15:19:53.502: D/OpenSSLSessionImpl(1596): Freeing OpenSSL session
    05-18 15:19:53.982: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 17495 objects / 885728 bytes in 77ms
    05-18 15:19:54.292: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 10363 objects / 441600 bytes in 71ms
    05-18 15:19:54.982: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 6564 objects / 298808 bytes in 71ms
    05-18 15:19:55.132: I/global(1596): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    05-18 15:19:55.212: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 843 objects / 85392 bytes in 65ms
    05-18 15:19:55.212: I/dalvikvm-heap(1596): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.120MB for 22148-byte allocation
    05-18 15:19:55.282: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 1 objects / 14776 bytes in 68ms
    05-18 15:19:56.012: I/global(1596): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    05-18 15:19:56.092: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 1758 objects / 193224 bytes in 67ms
    05-18 15:19:56.172: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 391 objects / 44792 bytes in 67ms
    05-18 15:19:56.252: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 411 objects / 62120 bytes in 66ms
    05-18 15:19:56.252: I/dalvikvm-heap(1596): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.194MB for 54142-byte allocation
    05-18 15:19:56.322: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 1 objects / 36104 bytes in 69ms
    05-18 15:19:56.413: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 955 objects / 67536 bytes in 70ms
    05-18 15:19:56.413: I/dalvikvm-heap(1596): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.237MB for 81208-byte allocation
    05-18 15:19:56.483: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 1 objects / 54152 bytes in 69ms
    05-18 15:19:56.852: I/global(1596): Default buffer size used in BufferedReader constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
    05-18 15:19:56.942: D/dalvikvm(1596): GC freed 1317 objects / 241880 bytes in 71ms
    05-18 15:19:57.112: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 0
    05-18 15:19:57.112: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 10
    05-18 15:19:57.122: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 20
    05-18 15:19:57.122: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 30
    05-18 15:19:57.122: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 40
    05-18 15:19:57.133: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 50
    05-18 15:19:57.133: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 70
    05-18 15:19:57.133: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 90
    05-18 15:19:57.133: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Progress Update: 100
    05-18 15:19:57.133: D/LOG_TAG(1596): Post-Execute
    05-18 15:19:57.513: W/InputManagerService(51): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@44c5f5a0
```

Comment: Is there anything consuming CPU on your UI (main) thread, by any chance?

Comment: I don't think so. I've tried it on different phones. This problem is not limited to AsyncTasks. I've tried threads too. I'm missing something. Some vital concept which I'm doing wrong over and over again. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the delay is due to **get()** method in `String response=GH.execute().get();`. It puts wait on the execution till the AsyncTask is completed.

As per Javadoc:

> **get()**: Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves
>   its result.

I think you should simply call `GH.execute();` to execute your AsyncTask wihtout affecting UI thread by putting it on hold.

Comment: I'm feeling pretty stupid right now. Solved the problem. Thanks. One question, if I can't use **get()**, how do I manage to return the values obtained in the background task. (I could add another returnable function in the class, but that's an alternative)

Comment: add your desired method in your activity and pass its instance to the constructor of AsyncTask. Once the AsyncTask hits onPostExecute method, call the method of your activity using its reference (which you received via constructor)